# get Text of string or edittext on specific position java

Tags: java, android

I have an `Edittext` field which contains few values entered by the user.
I want to get text which is indexed on position 5. for example,
if the user enter these values = 234asdf3+
I need to get value on position 5 which is "s" and i must get it in a string.
how can I do that?
I know I can get whole text in string via this code.

```
String s5 = currentcalc.getText().toString();
```

But, I need to get code of specific position.

Comment: did you try String.charAt(int index)?

Comment: String.valueOf(s5.charAt(4)); will get your character and convert it to the String, since you say you need a String.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 String s5 =String.valueOf(currentcalc.getText().toString().charAt(4));//since starts from 0
```

use this.

Comment: you are Great Dear but i have less than 15 reputation and not able to thumb up for you but i promise once i get reputation above 15 i obviously come back here and thumb up for you. Thanks again

Comment: i am new to this website and hope i'll learn everything soon on this site. many people like you are always helping me Greatly.